# GAPIT package for GWAS analysis

Tags: r

i got error in gapit pakage when use pca

whean i use gapit function with pca.total not ziro i got error :

```
>myGAPIT_17054 <-GAPIT(myY[,c(1,2)], # Y must consider the column Taxa and the column of the desired phenotype
                                G=myG,
                                CV=myCV,
                                KI = myKI,
                                PCA.total=2,
                                #Multiple_analysis=TRUE,
                                model=c("MLM","FarmCPU","Blink"),
                                SNP.P3D = TRUE,
                                Inter.Plot=TRUE,
                                file.output=T,
                                Geno.View.output = FALSE,
                                Phenotype.View= FALSE,SNP.FDR=1, cutOff = 0.05,FDRcut = TRUE,
                      SNP.test = TRUE,
                      SNP.fraction = 1)
```

"--------------------Final results presentations------------------------"
"Generating summary"
"Genomic Breeding Values (GBV) ..."
Error in t(KWO) %*% MASS::ginv(as.matrix(KW)) %*% UW :
requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
In addition: There were 40 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
Error in t(KWO) %*% MASS::ginv(as.matrix(KW)) %*% UW :
requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
"--------------------Final results presentations------------------------"

and stop process, how can fixt it?